# pyspark unable to overwrite specific partitioned data when writing data into hdfs

Tags: python, dataframe, hive, pyspark

I have a table `customer_table` which is partitioned base on below three columns. So, in hdfs it looks as below:

```
date=1901 > cus_id=A > cus_type=online > file
          > cus_id=B > cus_type=online > file
          > cus_id=C > cus_type=online > file
date=1902 > cus_id=A > cus_type=online > file
          > cus_id=B > cus_type=online > file
          > cus_id=C > cus_type=online > file
date=1903 > cus_id=A > cus_type=online > file
          > cus_id=B > cus_type=online > file
          > cus_id=C > cus_type=online > file
```

Now, I have filtered by input data and considered only the data for `cus_id = A`

```
df_filtered = df_input.filter(df.cus_id == "A")
df_filtered {dataframe has data from 1901, 1902 and 1903}
```

I have done data frame operations and the newly calculated data frame `df_filter_updated` has to overwrite into the customer_table

So, only the `cus_id=A` folder data has to be replaced in all the date=**** hdfs folders.

We are doing the below operation:

```
df_filter_updated.write.option("compression", "snappy").mode("overwrite")
.partitionby("date", "cus_id", "cus_type").parquet(hdfs_path)
```

But, it is overwriting the entire table instead of particular partitioned folders.
How can we achieve this way of overwriting?

Actually, why I'm doing this operation is to calculating new columns for all the old data present in the `customer_table`.

Comment: You don't. Filter for each year and save it into the partitioned path and even this break the table so you should repair the table.

Comment: Thanks, we can repair the table after insertion. But, when i overwrite new data for example ```cus_id = A```. Here i have to overwrite the file in all date=**** folders, that is not happening. It is overwriting entire data actually.

Comment: yes, that is expected behavior but you might try the save mode to append that will create the new file I think but not sure.